# Really strange behaviour with self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView with a picture but it is going over the frame of the picture since it is set to Aspect Fill Content Mode. So I tried setting:

```
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES
```

but after this I get really strange behaviour that the image will turn to this rhombus in the middle of the imageView. I have tried it with two different images and it is the same problem.

Here is before and after `clipsToBounds` images: (ignore the my profile behind it)

[image: before] [image: after]

Comment: Hmmm... Aspect Fill shouldn't make the image go over the frame (none of the fill modes should). I tried setting clipsToBounds to YES, but I don't see anything happen, so I can't duplicate your problem.

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your imageView? Do you use and transforms? Do you explicitly deal with layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've set the `cornerRadius` property to something quite high.

Try changing your:

```
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
```

Or remove any line that specify a cornerRadius that isn't 0.